# PHP - run bash script and display output in browser

Tags: php, bash

Having a problem with a PHP script which takes input from an HTML form, then runs a bash script.

The code works fine in that the bash script runs (permissions are all OK), but I need the output of the script to display in the browser. Can anyone comment on where I'm going wrong? Or if this isn't even possible? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . "\n";
    $ret  = file_put_contents('variables.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if ($ret === false) {
        die('There was a problem, please go back and try again');
    } else {
        $var = shell_exec('bash /var/www/html/script.bash -b');
        echo "<pre>$var</pre>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try removing the bash part from shell_exec.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately. The bash script runs and does what it is suppose to do, but I'd like the output to show in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure your script is sending output to stdOut? Can you post you script.bash code?